# Design pattern for bidirectional stream translator

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, bidirectional

I would like to design networking protocol implementation object to be entirely socket agnostic, and act purely as a bidirectional translator. So protocol object should be fed with objects or commands from "control" side and emit bytes from "network" side, and accept bytes from "network" side to be translated into objects/responses and emitted from "control" side.

I can't choose elegant design pattern to do this in Node.js. I want it to be fully `Stream` compatible, and I ended up with this approach so far:

```
socket = getSocketSomehow();
proto = new Protocol();

socket.pipe(proto.aux);
proto.aux.pipe(socket);

proto.write({ foo: 'this', bar: ['is', 'command'] });
proto.once('data', function(response) {
    console.log('this is response: ' + response.quux);
});
```

`proto` is collection of two cross-connected duplex streams, itself being `stream.Duplex`, as well as `aux`. Incoming network data goes into `proto.aux`, then is parsed and emitted from `proto` as objects. Incoming objects go to `proto` and are composed into bytes and emitted from `proto.aux`.

**Is there better way to do the same?**

Comment: Hard to say without understanding the application.

Comment: @JonathanM well, what is actually unclear? Say, this is either SOCKS4 implementation, binding control stream (where to BIND and how successful it was) and TCP socket (actual connection to SOCKS proxy); or XMLRPC implementation, emitting/accepting HTTP requests/responses on one side, and emitting/accepting RPC call/response objects on the other. Does this clarification actually change an answer even a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had ended with following approach. Code samples are in CoffeeScript for better readability.

---

`Bond` class implements `Duplex` stream interface, but binds together two unrelated streams, so reads and writes are proxied to separate streams.

```
'use strict'

{ EventEmitter } = require 'events'

class Bond extends EventEmitter
    proxyReadableMethod = (method) =>
        @::[method] = -> @_bondState.readable[method] arguments...

    proxyWritableMethod = (method) =>
        @::[method] = -> @_bondState.writable[method] arguments...

    proxyReadableMethod 'read'
    proxyReadableMethod 'setEncoding'
    proxyReadableMethod 'resume'
    proxyReadableMethod 'pause'
    proxyReadableMethod 'pipe'
    proxyReadableMethod 'unpipe'
    proxyReadableMethod 'unshift'
    proxyReadableMethod 'wrap'

    proxyWritableMethod 'write'
    proxyWritableMethod 'end'

    constructor: (readable, writable) ->
        super

        @_bondState = {}
        @_bondState.readable = readable
        @_bondState.writable = writable

        proxyEvent = (obj, event) =>
            obj.on event, => @emit event, arguments...

        proxyEvent readable, 'readable'
        proxyEvent readable, 'data'
        proxyEvent readable, 'end'
        proxyEvent readable, 'close'
        # proxyEvent readable, 'error'

        proxyEvent writable, 'drain'
        proxyEvent writable, 'finish'
        proxyEvent writable, 'pipe'
        proxyEvent writable, 'unpipe'
        # proxyEvent writable, 'error'

module.exports = Bond
```

---

`Protocol` aggregates two internal `Transform` streams — `Parser` and `Composer`. `Parser` takes data coming from `aux` side, and transforms it into something coming out from `ctl` side, while `Composer` does the reverse. `aux` and `ctl` are both bonds for parser and composer, but in different directions — so `aux` only deals with "composed" data coming in and out, and `ctl` side emits and accepts "parsed" data. My design decision was to expose `ctl` through `Protocol` itself, and `aux` is visible as instance variable.

`Protocol` exposes:

- `_parse`, `_compose` as `_transform`-like methods
- `_parseEnd`, `_composeEnd` as `_flush`-like methods
- `parsed`, `composed` as `push`-like methods
- `unparse`, `uncompose` as `unshift`-like methods

```
'use strict'

Bond = require './bond'
BacklogTransform = require './backlog-transform'

class Protocol extends Bond
    constructor: (options) ->
        @_protocolState = {}
        @_protocolState.options = options
        parser = @_protocolState.parser = new ParserTransform @
        composer = @_protocolState.composer = new ComposerTransform @

        parser.__name = 'parser'
        composer.__name = 'composer'

        proxyEvent = (source, event) =>
            source.on event, =>
                @emit event, arguments...

        proxyParserEvent = (event) =>
            proxyEvent @_protocolState.parser, event

        proxyComposerEvent = (event) =>
            proxyEvent @_protocolState.composer, event

        proxyParserEvent 'error'
        proxyComposerEvent 'error'

        super @_protocolState.parser, @_protocolState.composer
        @aux = @_protocolState.aux = new Bond @_protocolState.composer, @_protocolState.parser
        # @_protocolState.main = @main = new Bond @_protocolState.parser, @_protocolState.composer

    parsed: (chunk, encoding) ->
        @_protocolState.parser.push chunk, encoding

    composed: (chunk, encoding) ->
        @_protocolState.composer.push chunk, encoding

    unparse: (chunk, encoding) ->
        @_protocolState.parser.unshift chunk, encoding

    uncompose: (chunk, encoding) ->
        @_protocolState.composer.unshift chunk, encoding

    #
    _parse: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
        throw new TypeError 'not implemented'

    _compose: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
        throw new TypeError 'not implemented'

    _parseEnd: (callback) ->
        callback()

    _composeEnd: (callback) ->
        callback()

class ParserTransform extends BacklogTransform
    constructor: (@protocol) ->
        options = @protocol._protocolState.options
        super options, options.auxObjectMode, options.mainObjectMode

    __transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
        @protocol._parse chunk, encoding, callback

    __flush: (callback) ->
        @protocol._parseEnd callback

class ComposerTransform extends BacklogTransform
    constructor: (@protocol) ->
        options = @protocol._protocolState.options
        super options, options.mainObjectMode, options.auxObjectMode

    __transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
        @protocol._compose chunk, encoding, callback

    __flush: (callback) ->
        @protocol._composeEnd callback

module.exports = Protocol
```

---

`BacklogTransform` is utility class, extending `Transform` stream with an ability to unshift untransformed chunk back into queue by calling `unshift` method somewhere during `_transform`, so unshifted data will appear on next `_transform`, prepended to new chunk. Implementation is not as ideal as I would like it to be, unfortunately...

```
'use strict'

async = require 'async'
stream = require 'stream'

class BacklogTransform extends stream.Transform
    constructor: (options, writableObjectMode, readableObjectMode) ->
        options ?= {}

        super options
        @_writableState.objectMode = writableObjectMode ? options.writableObjectMode
        @_readableState.objectMode = readableObjectMode ? options.readableObjectMode
        @_backlogTransformState = {}
        @_backlogTransformState.backlog = []

    unshift: (chunk, encoding = null) ->
        if @_writableState.decodeStrings
            chunk = new Buffer chunk, encoding ? @_writableState.defaultEncoding

        @_backlogTransformState.backlog.unshift { chunk, encoding }

    _flushBacklog: (callback) ->
        backlog = @_backlogTransformState.backlog

        if backlog.length
            if @_writableState.objectMode
                async.forever(
                    (next) =>
                        return next {} if not backlog.length

                        { chunk, encoding } = backlog.shift()
                        @__transform chunk, encoding, (err) ->
                            return next { err } if err?

                            next null

                    ({ err }) ->
                        return callback err if err?

                        callback()
                )
            else
                chunks = (chunk for { chunk, encoding } in backlog)

                if @_writableState.decodeStrings
                    encoding = 'buffer'
                    chunk = Buffer.concat chunks
                else
                    encoding = backlog[0].encoding
                    for item in backlog[1..]
                        if encoding != item.encoding
                            encoding = null
                            break

                    chunk = chunks.join ''

                @_backlogTransformState.backlog = []
                @__transform chunk, encoding, callback
        else
            callback()

    _transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
        backlog = @_backlogTransformState.backlog

        if backlog.length
            backlog.push { chunk, encoding }

            @_flushBacklog callback
        else
            @__transform chunk, encoding, callback

    _flush: (callback) ->
        @_flushBacklog =>
            @__flush callback

    __transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
        throw new TypeError 'not implemented'

    __flush: (callback) ->
        callback()

module.exports = BacklogTransform
```